# Install PyQt4 for Python3.6 on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt4

I need to install PyQt4 for Python3.6 on Windows but I can not find any clear instructions of how to do it from source. Most of the pages that I found they suggest to use an executable but they are no longer provided for Windows.

https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Comment: Could you include what's inside the zip file in your question?

Comment: I downloaded the Windows source from the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

you can download PyQt4 from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/) choose PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4 and install it in the same path of python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the end I updated my script to use PyQt5.

Comment: You can't. The sip package requires python34.dll.